# PowerBI Custom Legend and Column Colours in Stacked bar chart

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

so I am trying to customise the colours for the legends. Basically what I am trying to do is to group the legends by colour. For example image we have refineries which are in different locations in the world. So for example if refineries 1, 2 & 3 are in Asia they should be coloured in green, and if refineries 4 & 5 are in Europe, then they should be coloured in blue. An example of this is shown below (created by excel):

[image]

Currently in PowerBI, this is my stacked chart:

[image]

So as you can see, the colours are dependent on the refineries, rather than on the locations (which are stored in a related Locations table).

Any idea of how this can be tackled in PowerBI please?

Much appreciated!

Comment: The second screenshot shows no locations or anything of the sort. Could you include both test data (e.g. csv) for a [mcve], and explain a bit further how the PowerBI result differs from the expected result?

Comment: Ok Jeroen, just updated the question to show you the full dashboard example, with the lookups I am considering. Where you see PAD - that is the locations related table

Answer (score 2):

It would be very useful for BI developers if you could customize and format a little bit in Power BI using the built-in tools and expressions, something similar to SSRS, where you can set a color property based on the report data. Hope features like that be implemented soon.

As far as I know you can use Data Colors Pane:

[image]

Very manual and I think it breaks when new legends are added.

Comment: Yes, but the data colours are for the legends directly. What I want is a little different. I need to set the colours of the legends based on another column (Locations). If the legend falls in a certain location, then it has a specific colour, while if it falls under another location, it has a different colour.

Comment: @Sambas23, Unfortunately that is not possible right now using the built-in visuals. You can create a [custom visual](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-custom-visuals-getting-started-with-developer-tools/) though.